# Virtual box NIGHTMARE

Tags: virtualbox

i'm trying to resolve this problem:

```
root@xisco-pc:/home/xisco# apt-get upgrade
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Calculando la actualización... Listo
Los siguientes paquetes se han retenido:
  linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic linux-signed-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-signed-image-generic-lts-utopic
Se actualizarán los siguientes paquetes:
  apt-transport-https apt-utils compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins
  compiz-plugins-default compizconfig-settings-manager
  gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 libcompizconfig0 libdecoration0 libnm-glib-vpn1
  liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-presentation-minimizer
  linux-libc-dev oxideqt-codecs-extra python-compizconfig
  python3-update-manager tcpdump update-manager update-manager-core virtualbox
25 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 5 no actualizados.
27 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se necesita descargar 0 B/47,0 MB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 3.083 kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] s
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 234100 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox_4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox.prerm: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: aviso: el subproceso script de `pre-removal' antiguo devolvió el código de salida de error 127
dpkg: probando el script del nuevo paquete en su lugar...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /var/cache/apt/archives/virtualbox_4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 el subproceso script pre-removal nuevo devolvió el código de salida de error 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox.postinst: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/virtualbox.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error al reorganizar:
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 127
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/virtualbox_4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea?

thank you very much

Solved!

```
apt-get remove virtualbox
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean



& this for update packages

apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: try reinstalling virtualbox

Comment: i recive this error reinstalling:

Answer (score 0):

The program `/usr/bin/pyclean` seems to be missing. Make sure the package `python-minimal` is installed.

Comment: can you help me to look up? i dont know how

Comment: Try to install it using `sudo apt-get install python-minimal`

Comment: i recive the same error

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-minimal`.  If that doesn't help: What does `ls -l /usr/bin/pyclean` print?